# Passing content of float32 to a int32 in C

Tags: c, embedded

**Problem:**

I would like to pass all the content of a float32 variable to a int32 however doing the following:

```
float32 source;
int32 destination;

source = 23.59463;         // Hex = 0x41BCC1CE 
destination = 0;           // Hex = 0x00000000
destination = source;      // Destination = 0x00000017 = 23
```

This does not pass all the content. I have tried casting, and tried to get the content indirectly but then I get issues with pointer types.

**Question:**

1) How can I grab all the content of the float32 into the int32?

Comment: Could the question be how to print a float as hex?  Or do you wish to manipulate the number?  Or do you have some interface that takes an `int32` which gets passed to a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a byte-by-byte copy, that's

```
assert(sizeof(source) == sizeof(destination));
memcpy(&destination, &source, sizeof(source));
```

Comment: I was trying to express a byte-to-byte copy, Thank you

Comment: Assertion here is a good extra. Though I would use compile time assertion for this to find out about possible problems sooner.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative answer, there's always fun with pointers:

```
destination = *(int32*)&source;
```

Comment: i am using this solution now, I have no idea what is happening. and it works. Thank you

Comment: @user2995676:  It takes the address of the float32 (a pointer), casts that to an int32 pointer (reinterpreting a pointer does not change the bit pattern of the referenced object), then dereferences it.  Because the dereference is of an int32 pointer, and dereferencing does not change the value, there is no float32 to int32 conversion - the bit pattern is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the assignment `destination = source` the `source` variable is *casted* to an integer, and thereby truncated.

One way of overcoming this problem is to use a `union`:

```
union U
{
    float32 f;
    int32   i;
};

union U u;
u.f = 23.59463;
printf("%08x\n", u.i);
```

**Note:** If you intend to send this integer (over network or serial communication) then you have to remember that different platform have different [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Doesn't this provoke undefined behavior because it reads a different `union` member than the one that was last set?

Comment: @larsmans no it doesn't, it's a common way in C to convert between binary formats.

Comment: @claptrap It's a common way, but I *think* it isn't officially supported by C standard. I can't find any proof to back that up now. But I suspect it could lead to aliasing problems in some cases.

Comment: @user694733: It is supported by C. Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.2.3 note 95: “If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good to know. It seems my information was old; this behaviour wasn't clearly defined in earlier standards. Have to be careful with older compilers.

Comment: @user694733: I quoted from a C 2011 draft, but it was in C 1999 Technical Corrigendum 3 and was arguably intended in original C 1999.

Answer (score 1):

If "all the content" means all the digits, you can multiply source to get fixed point destination.

```
destination = source * 100000;//23.59463 * 100000 = 2359463
```